# Issue with Tikz Package - Seeking work around with using minipage or makebox

Tags: graphics, alignment

I have included 3 MWE examples included with this issue I am experiencing just for illustration purposes only.

I'm trying to place an image either on the right side or left side of a page inside a minipage and with out spacing between text depending on whether or not the page is odd or even. (no issue with determining that aspect) I can achieve the required output using the TIKZ package - BUT - because there are so many of them in my file the tex file will not compile because it runs out of memory using pdflatex (and no I don't want to use LuaLatex as I would need to do way too much code reformatting) I have expanded memory to the limits of the Tex system but still will not compile regardless.

After reviewing the literate about Tex memory etc decided to re-asses whether I could achieve the same result without using TIKZ at all and thus hopefully resolve my memory issue.

Example one is using tikz and what I would like to achieve using Example 2, however I cant seem to figure out a way of not having spacing where the graphics is being inserted and also the flushright command puts  the image just slightly outside the textwidth.....

Example 3 is just using text to flushright but as you can see that aligns properly and as expected to the textwidth...

Any ideas or assistance would be appreciated

```
\documentclass[A4paper, 10pt]{book}

\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=297mm, left=20mm, right=30mm, top=20mm, bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{showframe}
\def\booktm{-30}


\begin{document}

\booktm \par \vspace{3.0\baselineskip}

EXAMPLE ONE - Using Tikz Package \par \vspace{1.0\baselineskip}
\begin{minipage}[c]{1.0\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\LARGE{JUST SOME TEXT HERE}\newline
and\newline
some more TEXT here\newline
and\newline
more and more TEXT\newline
\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\ \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \node[anchor=north east] at ($(current page.north east)+(\booktm mm,\the\numexpr-45mm)$) {\includegraphics[scale=0.20, keepaspectratio=true]{"shp"}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\par
\vspace{3.0\baselineskip}

EXAMPLE TWO - TRYING TO USE FLUSHRIGHT and MINIPAGE \par \vspace{1.0\baselineskip}
\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\
\begin{minipage}[c]{1.0\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\LARGE{JUST SOME STUFF HERE} \newline
and \newline
some more stuff here \newline
\begin{minipage}[c]{1.0\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.20, keepaspectratio=true]{"shp"}
  \end{flushright}
 \end{minipage}
and \newline
more and more stuff also \newline
\end{center}
 \end{minipage}
\par
\vspace{2.0\baselineskip}

Example 3 Just some text only \par \vspace{1.0\baselineskip}
 \begin{flushright}
 Text on line 1 \\
 Text on line 2 \\
 ...
 ...
 \end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

[image: shp]

Comment: Are you sure that Ti*k*Z is causing the issue (and not missing `\fi` after `\ifoddpage`)?

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat - in my full code the \fi is included in the code and yes I'm sure its tikz package because when I reduce the number of inputs or remove this part of the code the document compiles no issues - FYI the file is being generated using python code to feed the data to Latex directly and generates 20K pages for the document

Comment: Do you always put the picture at a fixed position like `($(current page.north east)+(\booktm mm,\the\numexpr-45mm)$)`? (Note that \numexpr` is not needed here, and that you could use `([xshift=\booktm mm,yshift=-45mm]current page.north east)` instead.) I am asking because in that case you could use `eso-pic`.

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat- Correct the image is position at the same place when it is placed in the page - we use a variable to reverse the position depending on whether its an odd or even page when generating the file - in this example I'm  only using the odd page positioning in my MWE

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat - Also regarding \the\numexpr -  we choose to do this as the book size output is a variable as well eg A4 US Letter Quartoetc etc eg \the\numexpr -45+-20mm as an example - so we calculate the position relative to the margins applied to the book size required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proposal using `eso-pic` to place the graphics.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}

\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=297mm, left=20mm, right=30mm, top=20mm, bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{showframe}
\def\booktm{-30}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}

\booktm \par \vspace{3.0\baselineskip}

EXAMPLE ONE - Using Tikz Package \par \vspace{1.0\baselineskip}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[c]{1.0\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\LARGE{JUST SOME TEXT HERE}\newline
and\newline
some more TEXT here\newline
and\newline
more and more TEXT\newline
\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
\setbox0\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.20,keepaspectratio=true]{example-image-duck}}%
\put(\LenToUnit{\booktm mm+\paperwidth-\wd0},\LenToUnit{\paperheight-45mm-\ht0})%
{\copy0}}%
\fi
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ill see If I can get eso-pic too work- many thanks